# Using struts 1 with dwr progress bar

Tags: java, ajax, struts, dwr

I am now trying to add a progress bar in my webpage.
Since I am using strut 1, so I have adopted the methods suggested in the following site:

http://kencochrane.blogspot.com/2006/03/ajax-struts-file-upload-progress-meter.html

I have also visited the dwr official site to check for the most updated version, and renew the code a bit.

I have copied the file I needed into my project and updated the file required (including the web.xml and struts-config.xml),

however, when I run my website, I get this error from firebug:

> dwr.engine._getObject is not a function

Anyone encounter this situation before?
Anything that I can do to fix this??
I suspect it is somehow related to my struts-config.xml and web.xml so below is my codes:

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Upload</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/execute/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
      <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
      <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
      <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
                               "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="UploadForm" type="com.struts.UploaderForm"/>
    </form-beans>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/Upload" 
            type="com.struts.UploadAction" 
            name="UploadForm" 
            scope="request" 
            input="/Upload.jsp">
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

    <controller multipartClass="com.upload.ExtendedMultiPartRequestHandler" />
    <message-resources parameter="com/struts/Resource"/>

</struts-config>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the required engine.js file in your HTML?  From [the docs](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/engine/index.html):

> engine.js is vital to DWR since it is used to marshal calls from the
>   dynamically generated interface JavaScript function, so it is needed
>   wherever DWR is used.
>
> All engine.js functions have the dwr.engine prefix.
>
> The engine.js file
>
> All DWR pages need the following script element to import the main DWR
>   engine.
>
> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'
>     src='/[YOUR-WEB-APP]/dwr/engine.js'>
> </script>
> ```